# How to loop through a list of string?

Tags: haskell

I suppose to input a list of words. If a word's last letter is the same as the first letter of another word, then we connect them and output a list of lists, which contain all possible connections.

Example: `convert(["apple","elephant","eraser", "tower","rank"])` will give

```
[["elephant", "eraser"], ["tower"], ["rank"], ["rank"], []]
```

I implemented my code as following:

```
convert :: [String] -> [[String]]
convert [] = []
convert [x] = []
convert (x : xs) = if last x == head (head xs)
    then [head xs] : [] : convert (x : (tail xs))
    else convert (x : (tail xs))
```

But this can only check the first element. How can I loop through the whole list and check each word?

===========================================================================

Ok. I have it done.

```
convert :: [String] -> [[String]]
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) = [u | u <- xs, last x == head u] : convert (xs)
```

Comment: Hint: [tails](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails), [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map). You might also like to check what happens if you include an empty `String` in your list when calling `convert`.

Comment: The input must be a list of words. So I don't worry about empty string. Unless the input is an empty list.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input & expected output? E.g., should `convert ["AB","Bx","By"] == [["ABx","ABy"],[],[]]`? (I.e., the value at each index of the output is the list of all words that matched that index in the input, even if there are 0.) It may be helpful to break the problem down into smaller steps—first write a function `merge :: String -> String -> Maybe String` where `merge "abc" "cde" == Just "abcde"` and `merge "abc" "xyz" == Nothing`. Then you can apply `merge` to each pair of words & collect the results, in various ways—`map`, list comprehensions, `do` notation, or recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to give an example. `convert ["apple","elephant","eraser", "tower","rank"]` will give `[["elephant", "eraser"], ["tower"], ["rank"], ["rank"], []]`. I know it's easier to break the function into little pieces. But I'm learning Haskell. I want to do it in a single function for practicing the syntax.

Comment: In your last case, `(head xs : tail xs)` is a complex way of writing `xs`

Comment: I know. I want to break it as the form convert(x:xs). I don't know if it does matter to concatenate them together

Comment: As you got the answer by yourself, please post the answer as an answer. Don't put it in the question post.